# SQL Server: How to use Spring jdbctemplate to pass array to stored procedure which returns multiple resultsets

Tags: sql-server, spring, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 which takes an array as an input param. According to http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html, I shall use TVP. However this is not supported in MSSQL JDBC driver. Therefore I cannot use SimpleJdbcCall to execute the stored procedure as I cannot pass the array parameter. I turned back to use JdbcTemplate to call this procedure like below:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("declare @d object_url_type;");
sb.append("insert into @d values (0, 'http://example.com', '/index.html', '');");
sb.append("insert into @d values (0, 'http://example.com', '/help.html', '');");
sb.append("exec procedure_name @objs=@d, @id=123");
jdbcTemplate.query(sb.toString(), new BeanPropertyRowMapper(ObjectData.class));
```

The problem I have is that the stored procedure returns two result sets. But it seems like I can only retrieve the first result set using jdbcTemplate. If I can use SimpleJdbcCall it would be easy to decare two result sets but unfortunately I cannot use it. I googled a lot but cannot find any solution to this problem. Can anyone pls help me on this? I guess I shall go back to use the raw JDBC way.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Spring StoredProcedure class instead of jdbcTemplate and then you can return multiple resultsets using declareParameter :

```java
package com.example;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlReturnResultSet;
import org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure;

public class ExampleStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {

    public class MyOtherRowMapper implements RowMapper<Long> {

        @Override
        public Long mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return rs.getLong("LONGCOLUMNNAME");
        }

    }

    public class MyRowMapper implements RowMapper<String> {

        @Override
        public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return rs.getString("STRINGCOLUMNMNAME");
        }

    }

    private static final String INPUT_PARAM = "@strParam";
    public static final String RESULTSET1 = "ResultSet1";
    public static final String RESULTSET2 = "ResultSet2";

    public ExampleStoredProcedure(DataSource dataSource, String storedProcName) {
        super(dataSource, storedProcName);
        this.declareParameters();
        compile();
    }

    public Map<String, Object> execute(String param) {
        Map<String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        inputs.put(INPUT_PARAM, param);
        Map<String, Object> results = super.execute(inputs);

        return results;
    }

    protected void declareParameters() {
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(INPUT_PARAM, Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet(RESULTSET1, new MyRowMapper()));
        declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet(RESULTSET2, new MyOtherRowMapper()));
    }

}
```

Invoking the stored procedure :

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class ExampleStoredProcedureTest {
    // assuming you pass the dataSource in via injection, etc, etc.
    @Autowired
    public ExampleStoredProcedure storedProc;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Map<String, Object> results = storedProc.execute("Test Parameter");

        // accessing the result sets
        List<?> rs1 = (List<?>) results.get(ExampleStoredProcedure.RESULTSET1);
        List<?> rs2 = (List<?>) results.get(ExampleStoredProcedure.RESULTSET2);

        // etc
    }

}
```